# launching UWP application from background app service

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP app service from which I need to launch the default browser application. I've followed the app service tutorial available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). From the AppService (which is a universal windows runtime component), I tried to open the browser using its URI scheme.

```
var uriBing = new Uri(@"http://www.bing.com");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing);
returnData.Add("Status", "OK");
```

this call gives me error of **`A method was called at an unexpected time.`**

Now my question is:
**Is it possible to open UWP application using its URI scheme from out of process app service?**

Comment: Do you have any updates for this thread?

Comment: I am launching applications using desktop app bridge and AUMIDs. my goal is to open applications and execute app-specific functionality. any suggestions of yours is appreciated.
Thanks for getting back :)

Comment: If you have used desktop extension, you could call `LaunchUriAsync` in extension side.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to open UWP application using its URI scheme from out of process app service?

I'm afraid, you can't call this method in the background. please refer [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-19041) document. *this API must be called from within an ASTA thread (also known as the UI thread)*.